# Detect HTTPS without SSL Termination

Tags: haproxy

I am trying to find out if https is in the address bar, as I have SSL termination before the HAPROXY, but I want HAPROXY to do the redirect if it is HTTP (a bit of an odd request i know).

I tried the:
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }

But it ends up in a never ending loops because it the packets already don't have SSL. Is there another way to get the prefix on a address bar? Also it does it for multiple domains, so trying to do this with a wildcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have SSL termination before the HAPROXY

I assume you mean SSL is terminated on an ELB?

If so:

```
redirect scheme https unless { hdr(x-forwarded-proto) -m str https }
```

ELB in http mode adds `X-Forwarded-Proto: https` on SSL connections.  The value is set to `http` otherwise.  Generate a redirect unless the header value matches what you expect.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do, and your fix worked perfectly, Thank you. I just didn't put that encase there was more generic fixes.

Comment: No, that's it. The `ssl_fc` (SSL/TLS on **f**ront-end **c**onnection) fetch only refers to the front-end socket of HAProxy itself.  That works when the browser is connecting directly to the proxy, but it's unaware of whether there's a device in front that is actually terminating the SSL, so the header provides the hint.